# Two association for a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project there is a user model and post model. In  that post belongs to the user( for author of the post) and has_and_belongs_to_many : posts ( for read and unread status).

How can I create a new post with current_user. Do I need to merge the current_user value in the parameter.  If I use @ user.posts.new (params)  looks for the join table. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why do you have a HABTM relationship on user?

Comment: For read and unread status. join table to store the user_id who read the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rails associations do not need to be named the same as the model. Its just a convention which makes it possible to create associations without any configuration.

Creating aliased associations is really simple:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: 'author_id'
end
```

You can even have multiple associations to the same table with this technique:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :editor, class_name: 'User'
end
```

To keep track of which users have visited which pages however you need a join table as this is a many to many association:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visits
  has_many :visitors, through: :visits
                      source: :user
end

class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visits
  has_many :visited_pages, through: :visits
                      source: :page
end
```

> How can I create a new post with current_user?

You can either do:

```
@post = current_user.posts.new(posts_params)
```

Or:

```
@post = Posts.new(posts_params) do |p|
  p.user = current_user
end
```

Using a block like in the later is a much cleaner technique if you need to combine the params from the user with other values then monkeying around with the params hash.